# A single list of users shared between several process using PM2 and Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pm2

What is the best way to have a single list of users which is shared between several  processes?. The processes are initiated using PM2.

The processes will have access to the list in order to add, remove, and check if a user exist in the list already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to use redis(or memocache, even mongodb) to store those user list.

Or you will have to handle very complex IPC in your case, since pm2 uses node cluter, based on child_process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an in-memory data store like Redis.

Redis runs as a separate process and serves requests on a TCP port(by default 6379). Redis is a key-value data store and can be used by all your node processes.

Here's how you can do it:

1. List item
2. Install redis. (https://redis.io/)
3. Install node client for redis:

> npm install --save redis

4. Now you can use redis to store your application state data and share it accross processes.

Refer [this](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis) link for code example.

Answer (score 0):

i just wrote a Job tracking logger for large web crawler system up to 1200 instances using redis.

Ok! Let's do it!

First you will need define it:

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client_redis = redis.createClient({
  retry_strategy: function(options) {
    if (options.error && options.error.code === "ECONNREFUSED") {
      // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with
      // a individual error
      return new Error("The server refused the connection");
    }
    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
      // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands
      // with a individual error
      return new Error("Retry time exhausted");
    }
    if (options.attempt > 10) {
      // End reconnecting with built in error
      return undefined;
    }
    // reconnect after
    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
  },
});
```

This function for update and create log.

```
function create_and_update_log(productName2, url2, proc, msg) {
    var data_value = {
        id: 'BESTBUY::DATA_LOG::'+md5(productName2 + url2),
        totalrv: 'WAIT',
        product: productName2,
        url: url2,
        process: proc,
        task: msg,
        timestamp: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss')
    };

    client_redis.set('BESTBUY::DATA_LOG::'+md5(productName2 + url2), JSON.stringify(data_value));
}
```

This function for query all data

```
async function get_log_redis() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        try {
            var logger_data = {
                logger: []
            };
            client_redis.multi()
                .keys('BESTBUY::DATA_LOG::*', function(err, replies) {
                    replies.forEach(function(reply, index) {
                        client_redis.get(reply, function(err, data) {
                            if (!data.includes("Total reviews left: 0")) {
                                logger_data.logger.push(JSON.parse(data));
                            }

                            if (index == replies.length - 1) {
                                resolve(logger_data);
                            }
                        });
                    });

                })
                .exec(function(err, replies) {});
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```

Remember to replace :

```
BESTBUY::DATA_LOG::
```

... with what you want to define.

And the final is how to fetch all log belong to my key name begin with "BESTBUY::DATA_LOG::"

```
            var log_obj_data = "";
            (async () => {
                var log_obj_data = await get_log_redis();

                response.writeHead(200, {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                });
                response.end(JSON.stringify(log_obj_data));
            })();
```